# How to Get google real-time feed displayed on your own webpage?

Tags: real-time, google-feed-api

I haven't found any API or else related to this. Does anyone know how to display the real-time feed of Google based on a few relevant keywords in relation to the content of the website ?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Google it, I'm sure Google knows about its own services...

Answer (score 0):

collecta.com
they have a widget that can do this, a [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collecta-search/) plugin and a [drupal](http://drupal.org/project/collecta) module are available too